# Map mean_se group_by combination can't handle a factor group_by

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'd like to get grouped means and corresponding se using the `mean_se` function from ggplot, but adding a group_by breaks the function. I've had to resort to pivoting and a longer summarize/mutate pipe, but would like to figure out how to do it in one go without all the data manipulation up-front. My dataset has 14 columns of interest + 1 group_by, but I'll use all of iris (hence skipping a `select()` pipe) for reproducibility.
Compare the first (doesn't work but is what I want) to the rest:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% #Error
  map(~(mean_se(.)))

iris %>% select(-Species) %>% 
  map(~(mean_se(.))) #global mean+se


iris %>% select(-Species) %>% 
  map_dfr(~(mean_se(.)), id = "Species") %>% broom::tidy() #Gives 3 but which is which and how so if Species is unselected?

iris %>%
  map_dfr(~(mean_se(.))) %>% broom::tidy() #Error 

iris %>%
  map_dfr(~(mean_se(.)), id = "Species") %>% broom::tidy() #Also error

iris %>%  #Runs but the 
  group_by(Species) %>% #output doesn't make sense, 
  group_modify(~  #there should only be 3 columns (y, ymin, ymax) not 13
    .x %>%
      map_dfc(mean_se))
```

map_dfr isn't respecting the `.id` command and I don't understand how I am getting 3 groups if the grouping variable has to be removed to avoid an `Error in stats::var(x) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct. Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(!contains("Species"), names_to = "key", values_to="val") %>% 
  group_by(Species, key) %>% 
  group_modify(~ mean_se(.x$val))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   Species, key [12]
   Species    key              y  ymin  ymax
   <fct>      <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa     Petal.Length 1.46  1.44  1.49 
 2 setosa     Petal.Width  0.246 0.231 0.261
 3 setosa     Sepal.Length 5.01  4.96  5.06 
 4 setosa     Sepal.Width  3.43  3.37  3.48 
 5 versicolor Petal.Length 4.26  4.19  4.33 
 6 versicolor Petal.Width  1.33  1.30  1.35 
 7 versicolor Sepal.Length 5.94  5.86  6.01 
 8 versicolor Sepal.Width  2.77  2.73  2.81 
 9 virginica  Petal.Length 5.55  5.47  5.63 
10 virginica  Petal.Width  2.03  1.99  2.06 
11 virginica  Sepal.Length 6.59  6.50  6.68 
12 virginica  Sepal.Width  2.97  2.93  3.02
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), mean_se))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length$y $ymin $ymax Sepal.Width$y $ymin $ymax Petal.Length$y $ymin $ymax Petal.Width$y $ymin $ymax
  <fct>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa               5.01  4.96  5.06          3.43  3.37  3.48           1.46  1.44  1.49         0.246 0.231 0.261
2 versicolor           5.94  5.86  6.01          2.77  2.73  2.81           4.26  4.19  4.33         1.33  1.30  1.35 
3 virginica            6.59  6.50  6.68          2.97  2.93  3.02           5.55  5.47  5.63         2.03  1.99  2.06
```

or if you want that in longer form:

```
iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), mean_se)) %>%
   pivot_longer(-Species)


# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Species    name         value$y $ymin $ymax
   <fct>      <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa     Sepal.Length   5.01  4.96  5.06 
 2 setosa     Sepal.Width    3.43  3.37  3.48 
 3 setosa     Petal.Length   1.46  1.44  1.49 
 4 setosa     Petal.Width    0.246 0.231 0.261
 5 versicolor Sepal.Length   5.94  5.86  6.01 
 6 versicolor Sepal.Width    2.77  2.73  2.81 
 7 versicolor Petal.Length   4.26  4.19  4.33 
 8 versicolor Petal.Width    1.33  1.30  1.35 
 9 virginica  Sepal.Length   6.59  6.50  6.68 
10 virginica  Sepal.Width    2.97  2.93  3.02 
11 virginica  Petal.Length   5.55  5.47  5.63 
12 virginica  Petal.Width    2.03  1.99  2.06
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` by 'Species', and use `map` to loop over the `list` and apply the `mean_se` on each column with `map`.  In the `split`, the `.` is used for extraction and for selecting the columns (`.[-5]` - last column i.e. grouping column Species is removed), thus we block the code in `{}` as more than one operation is done.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
iris %>% 
   {split(.[-5], .$Species)} %>% 
    map_dfr(map_dfr, mean_se, .id = 'Species')
```

-output

```
      Species     y      ymin      ymax
1      setosa 5.006 4.9561504 5.0558496
2      setosa 3.428 3.3743922 3.4816078
3      setosa 1.462 1.4374402 1.4865598
4      setosa 0.246 0.2310962 0.2609038
5  versicolor 5.936 5.8630024 6.0089976
6  versicolor 2.770 2.7256222 2.8143778
7  versicolor 4.260 4.1935446 4.3264554
8  versicolor 1.326 1.2980335 1.3539665
9   virginica 6.588 6.4980730 6.6779270
10  virginica 2.974 2.9283921 3.0196079
11  virginica 5.552 5.4739503 5.6300497
12  virginica 2.026 1.9871586 2.0648414
```

---

Or using `by`

```
do.call(rbind, by(iris[-5], iris$Species, FUN = Vectorize(mean_se)))
```

-output

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
y    5.006        3.428       1.462        0.246      
ymin 4.95615      3.374392    1.43744      0.2310962  
ymax 5.05585      3.481608    1.48656      0.2609038  
y    5.936        2.77        4.26         1.326      
ymin 5.863002     2.725622    4.193545     1.298034   
ymax 6.008998     2.814378    4.326455     1.353966   
y    6.588        2.974       5.552        2.026      
ymin 6.498073     2.928392    5.47395      1.987159   
ymax 6.677927     3.019608    5.63005      2.064841
```

Comment: Why does split need to index out -5 and why is it inside `{}`?

Comment: Both of the above solutions seem to be correct. In each case, we get 36 values. However, in solution one, we lose the connection with the `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width` `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width` variables. In turn, in the second solution, it gets lost in connection with the `Species` variable. It seems we should not assume that the data in a particular row is for that column and not for any other. I think it's better not to lose any information.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different syntax, but I would do the following:

```r
iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(contains("."), names_to = "key", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(Species, key) %>% 
  summarize(mean_se(value))
```

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Species'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 12 × 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Species    key              y  ymin  ymax
   <fct>      <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa     Petal.Length 1.46  1.44  1.49 
 2 setosa     Petal.Width  0.246 0.231 0.261
 3 setosa     Sepal.Length 5.01  4.96  5.06 
 4 setosa     Sepal.Width  3.43  3.37  3.48 
 5 versicolor Petal.Length 4.26  4.19  4.33 
 6 versicolor Petal.Width  1.33  1.30  1.35 
 7 versicolor Sepal.Length 5.94  5.86  6.01 
 8 versicolor Sepal.Width  2.77  2.73  2.81 
 9 virginica  Petal.Length 5.55  5.47  5.63 
10 virginica  Petal.Width  2.03  1.99  2.06 
11 virginica  Sepal.Length 6.59  6.50  6.68 
12 virginica  Sepal.Width  2.97  2.93  3.02
```